# Is it possible to create metadata only snapshots with LVM?

Tags: lvm

Using dm thin I understand it is now possible to store the metadata separately from the snapshot itself.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to create metadata only snapshots which do not incur the same I/O overhead? I am interested in which blocks have changed, but not the content of the old block.

My main motivation for this question is that I wonder if a backup solution using something like lvmsync (https://github.com/mpalmer/lvmsync) - but not incurring any significant overhead.

The documention is a bit light on information on how to achieve this, my thoughts were around creating a thin pool based on /dev/null or similar that silently discards when written to.

Answer (score 0):

The device mapper equivalent of `/dev/null` is the zero target (`dmsetup create --table '0 <nsectors> zero' myzeroes`). I think you'll be able to use this as a data device for your thin pool; and then snapshot your original volume (as an external origin) to track what changes are made to it. All of this is done outside of LVM; you need the full flexibility of DM while LVM caters to doing common use cases more conveniently and safely.

With help from [thin-provisioning.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/thin-provisioning.txt):

```
dmsetup create --table "0 $nsectors zero" myzeroes
dmsetup create pool \
    --table "0 $nsectors thin-pool $metadata_dev /dev/mapper/myzeroes \
    $data_block_size $low_water_mark"
thinnum=0
dmsetup message /dev/mapper/pool 0 "create_thin $thinnum"
origsectors=$(blockdev --getsz /dev/myorigin)
dmsetup create snap \
    --table "0 $origsectors thin /dev/mapper/pool $thinnum /dev/myorigin"
```